# Why does IE say it's done loading before new page loaded?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, internet-explorer, iis

I have an MVC site where a POST method does a `RedirectToAction()` to a method that takes a while (5-10 seconds) to load all the data before it does a `return View()`.

In Internet Explorer 11, after I post first page, the tab changes to say "Waiting for [Site Name]" with the spinning wheel, as expected. However, after a few seconds, the tab name reverts to the page title and the wheel stops. So it looks to the user like the server finished and returned the same page. Then, a few seconds later, when the sever is done, it jumps to the new page.

This is not an AJAX call or anything like that. Just a regular post with a regular redirect. To the best of my knowledge, the server isn't returning any data at all until the full 10 seconds are up and the page properly redirects.

Why would IE stop showing the user the "loading" information before the server has returned a response? It's not after a consistent amount of time either. Sometimes it goes away after 5 seconds, sometimes 3 seconds. Sometimes it shows it the full time (10 seconds) until the new page comes up, which is the behavior I would expect.

Comment: That's more a question for Microsoft than Stack Overflow. We can't give you much more of an answer than "IE sucks?". However, I'd say your main issue is that 10 second load time. Not sure what you're doing that's taking so long, but most likely it should be offloaded into a background process.

Comment: The redirect will be processed on the server side and the response will be a redirect response code, so like you say it should really only finish displaying the loading spinner once the page that you are redirected to has loaded.  Assuming that you _only_ have a simple redirect and a page that loads quickly.  Without seeing the code for the redirect and the code of the redirected page, it's hard to say.  I wonder if opening the developer tools might give away what's happening, maybe something is blocking the request.